# Nestjs/Swagger @ApiImplicitBody() not working

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, nestjs

I have a `@Post()` route that I'm trying to get tested in swagger, but the request doesn't show any kind of data types in the UI. I have another `@Post()`  route that is working and has stuff showing in swagger for the body, with just `@Body() user: CreatedUserDto` and everything is there.

Here's the one that's working:

```
  @Post('register')
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 201,
    description: 'Successful Registration of User Account.',
    type: UserCreatedDto,
  })
  async registerUser(@Body() user: CreateUserDto): Promise<UserCreatedDto> {....}
```

and here is the one that is not. I've also tried it without the `@ApiImplicitBody()` with no luck.

```
@ApiImplicitBody({
    name: 'user',
    type: LoginUserDto,
  })
  @ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'Successful Login!',
    type: LoginResponse,
  })
  @ApiResponse({ status: 400, description: 'Invalid login attempt' })
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  async login(
    @Request() req,
    @Body('user') user: LoginUserDto,
  ): Promise<LoginResponse> {
    try {
      return await this.authService.login(req.user);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

and this is the `LoginUserDto`

```
export class LoginUserDto {
  @ApiModelProperty()
  readonly userName: string;
  @ApiModelProperty()
  readonly password: string;
}
```

Comment: share your `LoginUserDto`

Comment: In the decorator?

Comment: Yes. show the code of `LoginUserDto`

Comment: I _think_ it has to do with adding `@Request() req` as the Swagger module _might_ not understand how to deal with that. Your DTO looks formatted correctly, so that's really my only guess at the moment.

Comment: So is there a way to access the request object AND have Swagger?